# password prompt keep on coming on the console

Tags: ssh, expect

I wrote below command, which will copy the `id_dsa.pub` file to other server as part of my auto login feature.  But every time below message is coming on the console:

```
spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /opt/mgtservices/.ssh/id_dsa.pub root@12.43.22.47:/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
Password: 
Password:
```

Below script I wrote for this:

```
function sshkeygenerate()
{
    if ! [ -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub ] ;then expect -c"   spawn ssh-keygen -t dsa -f $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa         
        expect y/n { send y\r ; exp_continue } expect passphrase): { send \r ; exp_continue}expect again: { send \r ; exp_continue}         
        spawn chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh && chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/*         
        exit "
    fi

    expect -c"spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub  root"@"12.43.22.47:/root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub    
    expect *assword: { send $ROOTPWD\r }expect yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }    
    spawn ssh -o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no root"@"12.43.22.47 \"chmod 755 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys\"    
    expect *assword: { send $ROOTPWD\r }expect yes/no { send yes\r ; exp_continue }    
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root"@"12.43.22.47 \"cat /root/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys\"
    expect *assword: { send $ROOTPWD\r }expect  yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
    sleep 1
    exit"
}
```

Comment: You might want to edit the code in your question. Looks like you missing several newlines.

Comment: Please edit your question to [format your source code correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Your code is extremely difficult to read, even looking at the markdown source of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a passwordless ssh to the destination server, then you won't need to enter the password while you will do the scp.

Assuming 192.168.0.11 is the destination machine:

1) ssh-keygen -t rsa

2) ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 mkdir -p .ssh

3) cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'

4) ssh sheena@192.168.0.11 "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"

Link for the refernce:

http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

Comment: thanks for the reply i have already done this in my original script . Updating the question for more information.

Comment: Just try to do manual ssh to the server after these steps, check whether you are able to login without the password.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` is much easier to use and you avoid problems with wrong access rights on dir and files in one command.

Comment: @Sumit , as you proposed i made the changes but still no success it seems like some permission issue . As a root user i couldn't able to do the ssh .